# Is there any other functions for excel Vlookup with different column index depend on referenced cell value?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I want to use `Vlookup` function to depend on a referenced cell value. Please look at my equation.

```
=IF(G2=1,VLOOKUP(A9,Pipe_Size_Chart,2,FALSE),IF(G2=2,VLOOKUP(A9,Pipe_Size_Chart,3,FALSE),IF(G2=3,VLOOKUP(A9,Pipe_Size_Chart,4,FALSE),IF(G2=4,VLOOKUP(A9,Pipe_Size_Chart,5,FALSE),IF(G2=5,VLOOKUP(A9,Pipe_Size_Chart,6,FALSE),IF(G2=6,VLOOKUP(A9,Pipe_Size_Chart,7,FALSE),IF(G2=7,VLOOKUP(A9,Pipe_Size_Chart,8,FALSE))))))))
```

Here, all `vlookup` function calls depend on cell `G2` value. Depend on its value, Column index for each function will be varied.But I want to use more advance or more compact function for that. I don't wan't to use macro. Can anyone please give me a piece of advice?

Comment: You don't need such a complicated formula. You formula can be replaced with VLOOKUP(A9, Pipe_Size_Chart,G2+1,FALSE)

Comment: just another wild guess `VLOOKUP(A9, Pipe_Size_Chart,$G$2+1,FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks a million bro! It really works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ifs are only 7, you can create a helping array that will match the values you need with your ifs. What I mean is that if you need for g2=1 to get 2, g2=2 to get 3 and so on, you can create as a first step an array with the numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 (we will cal this array "A1:A8").

Then in your VLOOKUP you can use the MATCH function:
=VLOOKUP(A9,Pipe_Size_Chart,MATCH(G2,A1:A8,0),FALSE)

The MATCH function will return the relative position of your lookup value, that I guess is in cell G2, inside this array we created and this will be your index column number. For this example if you have G2=6 then the MATCH function will return the number 7 because 6 is the seventh number in our array.

I hope this will help. If it doesn't solve your problem please provide a visual example from your table so we can give more accurate answers.